# I am relatively new to angular. How to put all the elements into the array of scope

Tags: html, angularjs

```
var app =  angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {


    $scope.products = [
        {
    name:"Nemke" ,        
    price:12,
    cover:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445251836269-d158eaa028a6?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=750&ixjsv=2.0.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1450",
    likes:0,
    dislikes:0,

        },

        {
        name:'James',
        price:32,
        cover:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432057322224-8916b9ed202a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=114ca17bc0b44dbf9696a24c48a3c18d"  ,likes:0,
    dislikes:0,
        },

        {
          name:'James',
        price:32,
        cover:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432057322224-8916b9ed202a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=114ca17bc0b44dbf9696a24c48a3c18d" ,
            likes:0,
    dislikes:0,
        }

    ]

    $scope.plusOne = function(index) { 
    $scope.products[index].likes += 1; 
    };    

    $scope.minusOne = function(index) { 
    $scope.products[index].dislikes += 1; 
    };   




 $scope.addName = function() {
 $scope.products.push($scope.name); 

};

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actual problem are you getting? Any errors in the console? I made a fiddle with your code and some supporting HTML, it seems to work as expected.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-repeat="product in products">
            <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
            <p>£{{product.price}}.00</p>
            <img src="{{product.cover}}"/>
            <ul>
                <li>Likes: {{product.likes}}</li>
                <li>Dislikes: {{product.dislikes}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button ng-click="plusOne($index)">Like</button>
            <button ng-click="minusOne($index)">Dislike</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danwellman/tjbxomfz/

Comment: danwellman, this works excellent but my problem is that i want to push all the elements of $scope.products when buttons is clicked to create a new <div></div> That contains $scope.name $scope.price $scope.cover and all the css of this div.